# Difference between gsheets and sheetsapi

Tags: flutter, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-signin

Does anyone know the difference between using [gsheets](https://pub.dev/packages/gsheets) and SheetsApi inside of [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis)? It seems I won't be able to use gsheets since I'm aiming to use [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) and apparently gsheets only allows service accounts. But I'm hoping I'll have better luck with SheetsApi.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is ownership
[Google APIs - sheets.v4 library](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/latest/sheets.v4/sheets.v4-library.html) is created by Google, the official one. So it includes all the APIs [services](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library), such as authentication and other Google Workspace apps

gsheets seems unofficial and it doesn't include other services for Google